# Calling a purely template lambda callback in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, callback, c++20

With C++20, we've gained templated lambdas, great!

```
[]<class T>(){};
```

Is it possible to call a lambda callback with a template parameter, but no argument to deduce it from?

For ex,

```
template <class Func>
void do_it(Func&& func) {
    // Call lambda with template here, but don't provide extra arguments.
    // func<int>(); ?
}

do_it([]<class T>(){ /* do something with T */ });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a lambda callback with a template parameter,
> but no argument to deduce it from?

This is probably what you want

```
template <class Func>
void do_it(Func&& func) {
  func.template operator()<int>();
}
```